# delete only one character when region is highlighted

Tags: emacs, elisp

I cannot find the setting that prevents deletion of an entire region when you have it highlighted and you hit backspace... (I just want it to delete one character even if a region is highlighted.) I already have

```
(delete-selection-mode 0)
```

and in custom-set-variables (I have cua-mode enabled for its rectangle functions),

```
'(cua-delete-selection nil)
```

but that is the behavior I get. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it is standard behaviour that emacs just deletes one character even if the region is highlighted. So I would look in my `.emacs` in order to find something that's disabling it.

Comment: Hmm. I thought that was the case too. The backspace key is bound to `delete-backward-char` so I don't know what's going on. I can't find anything in my .emacs file that would point to it, but it happens in all modes so it's gotta be something big..

Comment: Have you tried starting emacs via `emacs -Q` (which disables loading `.emacs` so you can check if it is indeed default behaviour)?

Comment: Ah,  yes - good idea. Deleting the region seems to be the default. I'm using GNU Emacs 23 on an OS X. I wonder if the nextstep build has anything to do with that...

Comment: As I understand, region deletion was introduced in or about emacs-24.  The accepted solution is documented (words not recipe) in the emacs manual - https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Using-Region.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

```
(setq delete-active-region nil)
```

is the answer. Thanks to all for toughing it out with me!

Comment: For this I had to turn cua-mode off also, since when the mark is active the `backspace` and `C-d` is bound to `cua-delete-region`. Unexpected, since `cua-enable-cua-keys` is set to `nil`, but I guess I'll do without cua-mode...

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem in vanilla Emacs (`emacs -q`).

Comment: Interesting!  I don't even have that variable...a quick Google search makes it seem like it only exists in delsel.el, which is included in GNU Emacs but apparently has to be `require`d before use.  I never knew about it; sorry I couldn't have been more help!

Comment: works for me with `emacs -q`... very odd, very odd... indeed. @rpdillon - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has different behavior depending on whether the highlighting was done with mouse or the keyboard.

Even in `transient-mark-mode`, if you set the mark and move the point, using backspace will not delete the region.  `delete-selection-mode` is a minor mode that changes this behavior.

When using the mouse to highlight a region, regardless of `delete-selection-mode`, using backspace will delete the region that was highlighted with the mouse.  From Section 25.1.1 of the manual:

"While the region remains active, typing  or  deletes the text in that
region and deactivates the mark; this behavior follows a convention established by other 
graphical programs, and it does *not* apply when you set the region any other way, 
including shift-selection (*note Shift Selection::)."

Based on this, it sounds like you're selecting the region using the mouse.  Is that correct?  Does the same behavior arise when using `shift-select-mode` or simply using mark and point?

Comment: Hi, actually I am only using the keyboard, with point and mark (not shift)... shift-selection-mode is nil.

Comment: Well, then something is askew.  I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on OS X and when I use the keyboard in any fashion to highlight a region (`transient-mark-mode` or not), and I backspace while the region is highlighted, I don't get this behavior.  I'll post again if I can figure out some setting that might be causing the problem you're having.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, very strange. I now found that `delete-forward-char` is also "broken" in the same way!

Comment: I just got the nightly build (Emacs 24) - even if I start that with "-Q", same behavior! Maybe I'm just screwed...

Comment: You know what, I applied a patch `http://citizen428.net/archives/432` to get the full-screen mode to operate. I wonder if this is causing the problems in my 23 and 24 (which includes the patch).

Comment: Of interest.  When you rebind `<delete>` to something (say, `(insert "a")`), that command is NOT called when you press `<delete>` when the region is selected with the mouse....

Comment: Yes- I tried before-advising `delete-backward-char` so the mark would become inactive, but that did not work either. @Trey: It was your blog by they way that led me to try cua-mode for its rectangles in the first place ;). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In ELisp, `0` is considered as true.

Try by setting

```
(setq delete-selection-mode nil)
```

Comment: I was not aware that delete-select-mode was also a variable... but your suggestion did not work, unforunately...

Comment: From your current buffer, try `Control ESC ESC` and enter the Lisp above `(setq delete-selection-mode nil)` (Enter). It should change the local behavior. Then try by setting the line in `.emacs` (may  work for all buffers). Finally you can use the `M-x` (Alt-x) `describe-variable` and enter (completion) `delete-selection-mode`. The menu will offer you first `customization`, in which you can save the value permanently.

Comment: Nope... actually I don't know about `Control ESC ESC` (doesn't work) but same as `M-:`, which is `(eval-expression)`? I'm not entirely new to emacs so I did try changing the variable with both `setq` and in `custom-set-variables` in my .emacs file and restarted emacs - but did not work. Strange...

Comment: Sorry it was `Control-x ESC ESC` to quick-edit the mini buffer and eval the `setq`. You can do also Alt-x `eval-expression`, 'Alt' being Meta - depending on your keyboard. It should work at least locally. This is `M-x` (Alt-x) and not `M-:`, to use `describe-variable`.

Comment: Hm, `C-x ESC ESC` is bound to `repeat-complex-command`. Are you sure it's not `M-:` for `eval-expression`? But in any case, problem solved! I think...

Comment: From the documentation of the variable: "Setting this variable directly does not take effect; either customize it (see the info node `Easy Customization') or call the function `delete-selection-mode'."

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, `cua-mode` doesn't handle this nicely. The simplest way to retain that mode without this problem would seem to be to redefine the cua keymap (see `cua--init-keymaps`) after initialising the mode, to unbind the various delete keys from `cua-delete-region`:

```
(add-hook 'cua-mode-hook 'my-cua-mode-hook)
(defun my-cua-mode-hook ()
  (define-key cua--region-keymap [remap delete-backward-char] 'delete-backward-char)
  (define-key cua--region-keymap [remap backward-delete-char] 'backward-delete-char)
  (define-key cua--region-keymap [remap backward-delete-char-untabify] 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
  (define-key cua--region-keymap [remap delete-char] 'delete-char))
```

Comment: This prevents CUA from stomping on <delete> in normal mode, but I can't get it to still delete region when actually *in* CUA mode.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this makes it work fine for the backspace. Even in cua mode:

```
;; Let backspace and delete be defined as usual if
;; nothing is highlighted, otherwise the marked region is deleted
(defun kill-something() (interactive)
  (if (and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
      (kill-region (point) (mark)) 
    (backward-delete-char-untabify 1)))
;;(global-set-key [delete] 'kill-something)
(global-set-key [backspace] 'kill-something)
```

[This code was found here.](http://www.csc.kth.se/~jesperc/Doc/emacs.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Add `(delete-selection-mode nil)` to your configuration file.

From the documentation inside Emacs:

> delete-selection-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `delsel.el'.
>
> (delete-selection-mode &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle Delete Selection mode. With prefix ARG, turn Delete Selection
>   mode on if ARG is positive, off if ARG is not positive.
>
> When Delete Selection mode is enabled, Transient Mark mode is also
>   enabled and typed text replaces the selection if the selection is
>   active.  Otherwise, typed text is just inserted at point regardless of
>   any selection.